# Remove Breadcrumb last node link

Tags: sxa

We are using the Sitecore SXA Breadcrumb component. It is showing perfectly fine on the page, however the last node (current page) is showing as a link. We don't want to show the last node as link.
Could someone assist me on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- front-end - your last element should contain CSS class: `last`. Use this information to manipulate existing HTML - modify with CSS/JSS
- back-end - modify view: `\Views\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb.cshtml` - i.e render `n-1` elements and last (`n`) separately.
- content - modify your variant definition. create 2 variations (1. for last element without link, 2. for the rest). Control which variant field version (with link or w/o link) should be used with `Rules` field.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this cannot be done out of the box.

You will need to override `Sitecore.XA.Feature.Navigation.Repositories.Breadcrumb.BreadcrumbRepository` and its `BuildBreadcrumb` method.

Here is code for custom `BuildBreadcrumb` method (not tested - check if it works for you):

```
public override IEnumerable<Item> BuildBreadcrumb(Item currentItem, Item rootItem)
{
    IEnumerable<Item> breadcrumb = base.BuildBreadcrumb(currentItem, rootItem);
    if (breadcrumb != null && breadcrumb.Any())
        return breadcrumb.Take(breadcrumb.Count() - 1);
    return breadcrumb;
}
```

and config to include register custom repository:

```
<sitecore>
  <services>
    <register
      serviceType="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Navigation.Repositories.Breadcrumb.IBreadcrumbRepository, Sitecore.XA.Feature.Navigation">
      <patch:attribute name="implementationType">custom.Feature.Navigation.Repositories.LanguageSelector.CustomBreadcrumbRepository, custom.Feature.Navigation</patch:attribute>
    </register>
  </services>
</sitecore>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS to target the last link in the breadcrumb and make it unclickable. Something like this might work.

```
ul.breadcrumb> li:last-of-type a {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: That would result in semantically incorrect markup. Anyone (and any software) should be able to parse the HTML *without* the CSS and see the same meaning as someone who does use the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The best way should be to clone the Breadcrumb component and modify the View file a bit.

```
    @if (Model.BreadcrumbElements.Any())
    {
        if (Model.BreadcrumbElements.Count() > 1)
        { 
            <div class="breadcrumb container container-large">
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                    <ul class="breadcrumb__list">
                    //Change the count to be used to Model.BreadcrumbElements.Count - 1
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.BreadcrumbElements.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            //The last item in this case will be previous to last one
                            if (i + 1 != Model.BreadcrumbElements.Count - 1)
                            {
                                <li class="breadcrumb__item">
                                    <a class="breadcrumb__link" href="@Model.BreadcrumbElements[i].Url">@Model.BreadcrumbElements[i].Name</a>
                                </li>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <li class="breadcrumb__item">
                                    <span class="breadcrumb__link breadcrumb__link--current" aria-current="page">@Model.BreadcrumbElements[i].Name</span>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        }
    }
```